# How can I express eigenvalues of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following $M \times 3$ matrix
$$\mathbf F = [\mathbf h_1, \mathbf h_2, \mathbf h_3],$$
with distinct non-zero singular values $\sigma_1 >\sigma_2 > \sigma_3$, where  $\mathbf h_k$'s are $M \times 1$ vector.
Then, we can easily see that matrix $\mathbf F \mathbf F^H$ has distinct non-zero eigenvalues $\sigma_1^2 > \sigma_2^2 > \sigma_3^2$.
My question is how can I obtain the eigenvalues of
$$\mathbf G = \mathbf F \mathbf F_2^H$$
where $\mathbf F_2 = [\mathbf h_1, -\mathbf h_2, -\mathbf h_3]$. Here, $\mathbf F_2$ has same singular values of $\mathbf F$. Note that it can be also expressed as
$$\mathbf G = \mathbf F \mathbf F_2^H = \mathbf F (\mathbf F \mathbf D)^H = \mathbf F \mathbf D \mathbf F^H$$, where $\mathbf D = diag([1, -1, -1])$.
Or at least $\mathbf G$ has distinct eigenvalues?

Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "how to obtain the eigenvalues" of $G$. Are you specifically trying to express these in terms of the singular values of $F$?

Comment: With [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), we can see that $G$ will have two negative eigenvalues and one positive eigenvalue.

Comment: Yes, I meant how can I express the eigenvalues of $\mathbf G$ in terms of the singular values of $\mathbf F$. Actually, I just want to know $\mathbf G$ has distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: It seems that "$\mathbf G$ will have two negative eigenvalues and one positive" is enough for me.  Can you give me more details? According to the link you provided, Sylvester's law of inertia, $\mathbf B = \mathbf S \mathbf A \mathbf S^T$ for non-singular $\mathbf S$ of the same size with $\mathbf A$. However, for my problem, $\mathbf F$ has not the same size with $\mathbf D$.

Comment: I’ll try to say more when I get the chance, but in a nutshell: the trick is to pad $D$ with extra zeros and add columns to $F$ in order to make it into an invertible matrix.

Comment: I got your point! Thank you.